# Using $exists in a MongoDB expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For background, if I want to compare two fields, I can't use the following syntax (because it compares to the literal string "$lastName" rather than the contents of the $lastName field):

```
"$match": { "firstName": { $ne : "$lastName"} }
```

I have to use this:

```
"$match": { "$expr": { $ne : [ "$firstName", "$lastName" ] } }
```

If I want to test that a field exists I must use the first format:

```
"$match": { "fullName": { "$exists": true } }
```

What I think would be the correct way for expressing the $exists operator in the latter format throws an error:

```
db.docs.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { "$expr": { "$exists": [ "$fullName", true ] } }
  }
])
assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$exists'",
        "code" : 168,
        "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed
```

Does this mean it is not possible to combine these operations, at least in some conditions? Specifically, suppose I want to find docs where **either** $fullName $exists **OR** $firstName $ne $lastName. Can that be expressed?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497150/mongodb-aggregate-by-field-exists

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to use the `$or` logical operator to do this.

```
{
   "$or": [
      {
         "$expr": {
            "$ne": [
               "$firstName",
               "$lastName"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "fullName": {
            "$exists": true
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

You last query failed because mongod thinks `$exists` is the expression you are passing the the `$expr` operator.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for, which is not addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497150/mongodb-aggregate-by-field-exists,  so my perspective is that it is not a duplicate, but I have a bias. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Will this be indexed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`$type` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) to get the type of a field. For fields that are not defined, this will be `"missing"`.

You can spot a missing field with this non-equality check:

```js
{$ne: [{$type: "$field"}, "missing"]}
```

Note that fields that are present but set to `null` will have the type `"null"`, so you may also need to check for that case explicitly, c.f. the handy [type table](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#available-types) in the documentation.

For your context, the full aggregation pipeline stage checking both equality between first- and last name *and* that a full name field exists, could be something like this:

```js
{
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        { "$ne": [ { "$type": "$fullName" }, "missing" ] },
        { "$ne": [ "$firstName", "$lastName" ] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).