# MongoDB - create a boolean field to test some subfield's existence

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a `$project` stage, I want to **create a dummy** (boolean) field which will be:

- **`true` if some subfield exists**
- **`false`** otherwise

This is my data. The subfield of interest is `address.country`, which may be missing:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1", 
    "name" : "John", 
    "address" : {
        "city" : "New York", 
        "country" : "USA"
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2", 
    "name" : "Paul", 
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Paris"
    }
}
```

The user named Paul has **no `address.country` subfield**, so I want his dummy field to be `false`.

Here is what I tried:

```
db.getCollection("items").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {

            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "name": true,
                "has_country": { "$address.country": { "$exists": true } }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

This failed with `InvalidPipelineOperator` and message `Unrecognized expression '$address.country'`. I found the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497150/mongodb-aggregate-by-field-exists) but this use case is slightly different and the answer was not very understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comparing the subfield to `null`** does the trick:

```
db.getCollection("items").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {

            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "name": true,
                "has_country": { "$gt": [ "$address.country", null ] }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

On the mentioned data, this returns the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "1", 
    "name" : "John", 
    "has_country" : true
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2", 
    "name" : "Paul", 
    "has_country" : false
}
```