# Filter array element which does not have a specific field in MondoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `people` collection in mongodb like below.

**MongoDB version:4.0.13**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dcbeb97e184e0f527c6a3e7"),
    "name" : "nithin",
    "age" : 35.0,
    "addresses" : [ 
        {
            "street" : "xyz",
            "city" : "Tvm"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "pqr",
            "city" : "KLM"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dcbebe4e184e0f527c6a3e8"),
    "name" : "akash",
    "age" : 21.0,
    "addresses" : [ 
        {
            "street" : "lon",
            "city" : "London"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "par",
            "city" : "paris"
        }, 
        {
            "street" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to filter out all the addresses which doesn't have `city` property. What i achieved so far is this

```
db.getCollection('People').aggregate([

    {
        $project:
        {
            "name":1,
            "age":1,
            "addresses":
            {
                $filter:
                {
                    input:"$addresses",
                    as:"address",
                    cond:{$not:["$$address.city"]}
                }
            }

        }   


    }

])
```

**Result:** I am getting all addresses without `city` property(*this is exactly the opposite of what i need*). I couldn't find any help from SO. how to negate a `not` result

I also tried this

```
        $filter:
        {
            input:"$addresses",
            as:"address",
            cond:{"$exists":["$$address.city":true]}
        }
```

**Result:**

> Error: Line 14: Unexpected token :

Comment: See ths post on [MongoDB aggregate by field exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497150/mongodb-aggregate-by-field-exists). The answer by @Delcon shows two options; the second one will work as a `$filter`'s condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have aggregation in this case. You can just use find with [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator:

```
db.people.find({
    addresses: {$elemMatch : {city: {$exists: false}}}
})
```

But if you want to use aggregation then you can do match on the same query:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {$match: {addresses: {$elemMatch : {city: {$exists: false}}}}}
])
```

Alternatively you can do it like shown below, but I assume elemMatch will work faster:

```
db.people.aggregate([
{$unwind: '$addresses'},
{$match: {"addresses.city" : {$exists: false}}}
{$group: { _id : '$_id', addresses: {$addToSet: "$addresses"}}}
])
```